# WPF Prevent keyboard invocation

Tags: wpf, textbox, keyboard, windows-10, focus

I'm developing a WPF application with .NET Framework 4.6.2 on Windows 10.
With this framework, when a TextBox gains the focus so the keyboard appears.
It is nice but how do disable the automatic invocation of this keyboard only on one TextBox ?
Indeed, if I set ReadOnly="True" then the keyboard continues to appear.

Comment: Did you try to override the OnCreateAutomationPeer() method as suggested here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845538/disable-virtual-keyboard-in-windows-10-tablet-mode-for-one-application

Comment: Making it Disabled(IsEnabled=false) instead of ReadOnly is not an option?

Comment: @mm8 : Extend TextBox works like a charm. I thought there was an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `OnCreateAutomationPeer()` method of the `TextBox` class as suggested by @Stalker here:

[Disable virtual Keyboard in Windows 10 Tablet Mode for one Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845538/disable-virtual-keyboard-in-windows-10-tablet-mode-for-one-application)

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new FrameworkElementAutomationPeer(this);
    }
}
```