# Windows touch keyboard appearing in controls without text input

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-10, touch, legacy

In MFC, how do I stop the touch keyboard from appearing when selecting controls without text inputs? Specifically, `CComboBox`-derived and original `CListBox` controls. The issue occurs in a large C++ application for touchscreen tablets running Windows 10. Bizarrely, selecting any `CEdit` control in the application solves the issue until the application restarts.

I've been looking at [`InputScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/use-input-scope-to-change-the-touch-keyboard), [`AutomationPeer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084739/disable-automatic-opening-of-touch-keyboard-tabtip-exe-on-textbox-focus-on-win), and even killing the keyboard process `TabTip.exe` after it appears, but none of these prevent the keyboard from showing in the first place.

A previous solution involved changing the "Automatically show touch keyboard" registry setting `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke` on focus change, but alerting the touch keyboard with `SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE)` added unacceptable delay to the UI.

Comment: you should add a minimal code sample, so we can follow and fix this issue.

Comment: @TomTom Attempting to reduce the issue to a minimal code sample is a good idea, I will attempt this in the future. I realized that my own question mentions a low-impact workaround: so for now I briefly focus a CEdit on application startup with appropriate "this is devilry" code comments. When I get more time I'll look into the root cause.