# Virtual Keyboard pops up in Windows 10 when clicking anywhere on my WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

I'm writing a WPF application for a Windows tablet, and I need the virtual keyboard to open when, and only when, the user touches a text field.
Until now I've been using Windows 7 and it worked as intended.

But now I am switching to Windows 10 and the virtual keyboard pops up anytime the user touches anywhere on the application (apart from buttons).

How can I make the virtual keyboard work the way it does on Windows 7?

[To activate the virtual keyboard in Windows 10 I'm going to Settings > Devices > Typing and switch on the option "Show the touch  keyboard when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached"]

Thanks for your help, and sorry if I messed something up, it's my first question here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable virtual Keyboard in Windows 10 Tablet Mode for one Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845538/disable-virtual-keyboard-in-windows-10-tablet-mode-for-one-application)

Comment: Thank you, but it does not answer. That user from that question wants to stop the keyboard from from opening when clicking on a text field. I want it to open, but ONLY when clicking on a text field, and not when clicking on anywhere else on the application.

Comment: That answer explains how to stop the virtual keyboard from opening. Selectively applying that solution gets you what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I will look into that if I won't be able to find the true reason behind the behavior. Thanks again for the help, @IInspectable